# Selenium Find Element Based on String in Text or Attribute

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to have Selenium find an element based on a string that can be contained in the element's text or any attribute, and I'm wondering if there's some wildcard I can implement to capture all this without having to use multi-condition OR logic.  What I'm using right now that works is ...

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@title,'foobar') or contains(.,'foobar')]"));
```

And I wanted to know if there's a way to use a wildcard instead of the specific attribute (@title) that also encapsulates element text like the 2nd part of the OR condition does.

Comment: I don't think so, but something that might help you arrive at a more definitive answer is [here](http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester).

Comment: Is there even at least a way to wildcard just the attribute-specific portion (like turning just @title into any attribute) but leaving out text()?

Comment: Can you give us an idea of why you want to do this? How are you using this?

Comment: Basically I have 3 different pages, each with an element containing this string in different ways as I've described above, and I want to implement an ExpectedConditions wait that waits for this element to be present or visible.

Comment: So you'd have to write 3 different functions and you're trying to boil it down to just one? Why?

Comment: Both for learning's sake and if I get a 4th page in the future that uses it differently than the other three, the code will still successfully find the element.

Answer (score 35):

This will give all elements that contains text `foobar`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'foobar')]]"));
```

If you want exact match,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text() = 'foobar']"));
```

Or you can execute Javascript using JQuery in Selenium

This will return all web elements containing the text from parent to the last child, hence I am using the jquery selector `:last` to get the inner most node that contains this text, but this may not be always accurate, if you have multiple nodes containing same text.

```
(WebElement)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return $(\":contains('foobar'):last\").get(0);");
```

If you want exact match for the above, you need to run a filter on the results,

```
(WebElement)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return $(\":contains('foobar')\").filter(function() {" +
    "return $(this).text().trim() === 'foobar'}).get(0);");
```

jQuery returns an array of Elements, if you have only one web element on the page with that particular text you will get an array of one element. I am doing `.get(0)` to get that first element of the array and cast it to a `WebElement`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't seem either of the top two will cover the case where an attribute like @title contains the string.

Comment: @user2150250 when you say `@title`, you mean the title of the page right? The `<title>` tag inside `<head>`. I tested the xpath for this page itself, `//*[text() = 'java - Selenium Find Element Based on String in Text or Attribute - Stack Overflow']` and it gave the `title` webelement. I am not sure if I understand right, the last 2 lines of your question is a little unclear to me.

Comment: Actually it's just the `title` attribute of a WebElement, in this case a `button` element.  It's not the page title.

Answer (score 5):

This will return the element with text `foobar`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='foobar']"))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Text Containing

To find an **element with the text** (displayed in the HTML page) **containing a specific text**, you can use the following XPath:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'text_to_be_contained')]
```

- ***'*'***, **selects all elements** in the document, regardless of the tag name. You can **replace the asterisk (*) with a specific tag name** if you want to search within a particular tag type.
- ***[contains(text(), 'text_to_be_contained')]*** is a condition that **checks if the text contains** the **specified text ('text_to_be_contained')**. This will match elements whose text attribute contains the specified text, even if it is part of a larger text value.
- ***'text_to_be_contained',*** should be the **text you want to find**

## Attribute Containing

To find an **element with** the **attribute containing** a specific text, you can use the following XPath expression:

```
//*[contains(@attribute_name, 'text_to_be_contained')]
```

- Replace ***'attribute_name'*** with the actual **name of the attribute** you want to search within, such as: ***class***, ***name***, ***href***, ***value***, or ***any other***

## Text/Attribute Is Equal

To find an **element with** the **text or attribute** a **matching exactly** a specific text, you can use the following XPath expressions:
For the text

**For the text:**

```
//*[text()='exact_text']
```

**For the attribute:**

```
//*[@attribute_name='exact_text']
```

- ***'exact_text',*** should be the **text you want to find**