# How to locate the button with text as Comment as per the html using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I am using Xpath helper in chrome extension to find xpath for python programming. I have read the documentation but is there a better guide out there.

HTML  is as follows:

```
<form class="addComment expand" data-id="9644797">
    <img src="https://ctl.s6img.com/society6/img/g2taHIrokQ01R_67jS8ulaWI2wk/h_150,w_150/users/avatar/~artwork/s6-original-art-uploads/society6/uploads/u/sul97/avatar_asset/d837ee10016843a3bba9ae3310cc338d" width="25" height="25">
    <textarea placeholder="Add a comment..." data-button="9644797"></textarea>
    <button id="b9644797">Comment</button>
</form>
```

Can someone show me an example to click the button of this path? I have tried to use it but didnt work

```
submit_comment = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[@class='gr__society6_com']/body[@class='platform- desktop']/div[@id='wrap']/div[@id='content']/div[@id='MySociety']/div[@class='one-col clearfix']/ul[@id='Mason']/li[@id='9649102']/div[@class='item-wrap']/div[@class='comments']/form[@class='addComment expand']/button[@id='b9649102']").click()
```

Comment: *"html example"*... No it's not an HTML example... Share HTML, not XPath

Comment: added html example here

Comment: Why do you need a complicated xpath? Why not just use the id of the button? `//button[@id='b9644797']`

Comment: @BryanOakley  : because the id is random generated. So we can’t rely on this id.

Comment: Your `<img...` tag is not closed, so your markup is not well-formed. Maybe that's a cause for misbehaviour.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Find Element Based on String in Text or Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259865/selenium-find-element-based-on-string-in-text-or-attribute)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The xpath would be :

```
//button[text()='Comment']
```

However, you should introduce webdriver wait for more stability in your code.

.`click()` method return void. So invoking click method and storing in a variable doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: also is webdriver wait is same as time.sleep() ?

Comment: time.sleep() is extreme case of webdriverwait. You can refer this link https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html for more details.